# How to export data from Excel to a valid Xml?

Tags: xml, excel, xsd, export

I have an Excel table with some data that I would like to export to an Xml file.
This exported Xml needs to be valid against an Xsd.

Note that all the formatting and validation must be done inside Excel because it'll be the only tool available to the person who will do the export.

Any recommendation to get this task done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save your file in xml format from Excel. This is known as MS Office XML. Documentation (and schema) is available for both Office [2003](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FE118952-3547-420A-A412-00A2662442D9) and [2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=15805380-f2c0-4b80-9ad1-2cb0c300aef9).

Comment: That's a schema reference. It's not an actual tool that one could SAVE-AS for example an Excel file directly into XML, which is what the question is asking.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a very old question but just in case some one else bumps in..

Accepted answer is good but XMLSS is far more complicated(though it's valid XML),  I thought of sharing [this resource on Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA102635091033.aspx).  It explains everything step by step.

Another option is to create a CSV file and then convert it into XML using XI - There was an article about it [on IBM developer works](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-wxxm9/index.html) which can do the job quite well.

[This Java API](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/) may also be of interest for few.

Answer (score 1):

two things, write a plugin for excel, or convert the excelfile to xml and create the xsd. Edit the xml in excel and you will have the validaion in excel against that.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP011429481033.aspx